# add to wishlist button not showing on product page

Tags: magento2, product, wishlist

I did enable the wishlist module, but I don't see the "Add to wishlist" button or link inside the product page.
What can I do? Can I manually add this "Add to wishlist" link to the product page or even category page as well?

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The wishlist configurations can be found in the following section and the highlighted config should be set to "Yes"
[image]

Also please check if any of customized modules / themes have removed the Wishlist feature from the layout files -
view/frontend/layout/catalog_category_view.xml
view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

In default Magento the above two files can be found in vendor/magento/module-wishlist/

```
<referenceBlock name="product.info.addto">
   <block class="Magento\Wishlist\Block\Catalog\Product\View\AddTo\Wishlist" name="view.addto.wishlist"                       template="Magento_Wishlist::catalog/product/view/addto/wishlist.phtml" />
</referenceBlock>
```

Comment: I did try to add the above block inside the custom theme xml, don't know why it not showing the "add to wishlist" button.

Answer (score 0):

Please check on this file /Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml or the module default.xml  file, if this code is available so just remove it and check. I think it might have been removed using XML files.

```
<referenceBlock name="wishlist_sidebar" remove="true" />
<referenceBlock name="view.addto.wishlist" remove="true" />
<referenceBlock name="category.product.addto.wishlist" remove="true" />
```